# bootstrap nav bar not appearing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with Bootstrap. The following is my application page in rails with postgresql and turbolinks disabled. Let me know what I am doing wrong, I cannot figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Website</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-
expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>


<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

[The page looks as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAjLC.png)
[Browser console as follows, Using Bootstrap Gem and jquery Gem, let me know why I am recieving errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQ0M.png)

Comment: Any reason you're not using the bootstrap gem?

Comment: Can you add the output in the browser console?

Comment: I added console image. No reason why Im not using the gem, I just started learning bootstrap.

Comment: The browser console I meant, you need to add both things the css file and the js file.

Comment: Just switched to the ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

You only imported bootstrap's CSS. You need the JS too.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Better to use the bootstrap gem, I frequently use [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Comment: I am using the bootstrap gem and jquery gem. It is working now!